# Python: How to increment outer for loop from a nested inner for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, nested-loops

There are already several good answers to this question [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13410392/python-for-increment-inner-loop). Here, I was trying to increment the '`i`' in outer `for-loop` from inner `for-loop` and did not work as expected. Therefore posting this question and answer. Hoping, it may help someone in future.

```
x = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
for i in x:  
  print(x[i])  
  for j in x:
    i += 1
```

Output:

```
i:0; x[i]:0
i:1; x[i]:1
i:2; x[i]:2
i:3; x[i]:3
i:4; x[i]:4
i:5; x[i]:5
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python for increment inner loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13410392/python-for-increment-inner-loop)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer:

1. Increment the '`start`' in `range(start, stop, step)`
2. Then, check for `iterator >= start`

Code:

```
x = [0,1,2,3,4,5,]
x_start=0

for i in range(x_start, len(x)):

  if(i>=x_start):    
    print('i:{}; x[i]:{}'.format(i, x[i]))

    for j in range(2):
      x_start += 1
```

Output:

```
i:0; x[i]:0
i:2; x[i]:2
i:4; x[i]:4
```