# Most Pythonic way to iterate by multiples

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was reviewing some algorithms and they had a for loop that increases by a constant multiple. What would be the most Pythonic way of solving this?

This is not an issue of how to solve the problem, but more of a discussion on what the best solution would be?

This is the Java snip:

```
for (int i = 1; i <=n; i *= c) {
    // some stuff
}
```

Here is an actual solution in python. I don't think it is the most Pythonic method:

```py
i = 1
while i < limit:
    # some stuff, remember to use i - 1 as array index
    i *= constant
```

Pythonic way I could see (That does not exist):

```py
for i in mrange(1, limit, c):
    # some stuff
```

First post here. Hope I tagged and all correctly...

Comment: It very well may be. I just feel like storing a counting value and manually updating it is not Pythonic...

Comment: I don't think it is, this is exponential and [python for increment inner loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13410392/python-for-increment-inner-loop) is a linear increment.  This is specifically referring to the multiple case where there isn't a "range" alternative" (that I know of).

Comment: that's where I like C/Php (for such cases)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You still can do this :

```
def mrange(start, stop, step):
    i = start
    while i < stop:
        yield i
        i *= step
```

And then :

```
for i in mrange(1, 100, 4):
    print(i)
```

Prints :

```
1
4
16
64
```

Python cannot provide default range functions to fit every needs, but it is pythonic to create your own generators.

If you don't like this solution, the `while` alternative looks ok too.

Comment: @Adam_Karlstedt `range` can only provide an arithmetic sequence.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `itertools.accumulate`; start with a range 1 to `n`, then apply a function which multiplies its first argument by your constant and ignores its second argument.

```
>>> from itertools import accumulate
>>> [x for x in accumulate(range(1,10), lambda x,_: 4*x)]
[1, 4, 16, 64, 256, 1024, 4096, 16384, 65536]
```

Having missed that you want to take the values less than `n`, start with the infinite sequence `[c, c**2, c**3, c**4, ...]` and use `takewhile` to "filter" it. (Also, I just realized you only need `map`, not `accumulate`, although `accumulate` may be more efficient. Note the difference in starting points when using `map` vs `accumulate`, too.):

```
>>> from itertools import count, takewhile
>>> n = 100
>>> [x for x in takewhile(lambda x: x < n, map(lambda x: 4**x, count(0)))]
[1, 4, 16, 64]
>>> [x for x in takewhile(lambda x: x < n, accumulate(count(1), lambda x,_: x*4))]
[1, 4, 16, 64]
```

Comment: I also had intention for `accumulate` but the looping must not exceed the upper bond `10`

Comment: Ah, misread the question. I'll update with `takewhile` and `count`.

Comment: @chepner, it'll getting grow )

Answer (score 0):

Using math module:-

```
for i in range(math.ceil(math.log(limit, const))):
    # code goes here
```

Ex:-

```
>>> for i in range(math.ceil(math.log(20, 2))):
...     print("runs")
... 
runs
runs
runs
runs
runs
```

which is similar to:-

```
i = 1
while i< 20:
    print('runs')
    i*=2
```

Finally; in easy seeming way:-

```
>>> import math
>>> mrange = lambda i, limit, const: range(i, math.ceil(math.log(limit, const)))
>>> for i in mrange(0, 20, 2):
        print('whoa')
.. 
whoa
whoa
whoa
whoa
whoa
```

Comment: I am not sure about this as the objective is to be Pythonic and this seems harder to read than the original while loop...