# I am getting Error : list assignment index out of range

Tags: python-3.x

```
def encryptRailFence(text,key):
    a=text
    b=[]
    for i in range(key):
        if i % 2 == 0:
            b.append(a[i])
        else:
            b[i]=a[i]
        i += 1
    print(b)

encryptRailFence('Vijay',2)
```

The below function throws error `list assignment index out of range`. I am not able to figure out the cause of the error

Answer (score 1):

Take a example:

1. When `i` is `0`, you are appending one element to the list `b`.
2. When `i` is `1`, you are using `b[1] = a[1]`,but the size of `b` is 1 and you cannot access `b[1]`, that's why you are getting `index out of range` error.

The line `i+=1` won't change the value of i used in the iteration. For reference see [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13410392/python-for-increment-inner-loop)