# While Loop in python without number repition and limiting to a scope

Tags: python, while-loop

I want a while loop with increment of 10 without repeating the starting number in python. This is what i have done, and the result i am getting, I have written the required result below for further clarifications. Thank you.

```
limitstart = 0
limitend = 0
while limitstart < 55:
    limitstart = limitend
    limitend = limitstart + 10
    print (limitstart)
    print (limitend)
    print ("new batch")
```

This is my result.

```
0
10
new batch
10
20
new batch
20
30
new batch
30
40
new batch
40
50
new batch
50
60
new batch
new batch
60
70
new batch
```

The result i want is :

```
1
10
new batch
11
20
new batch
21
30
new batch
31
40
new batch
41
50
new batch
51
55
```

Comment: Sounds like you actually want a for loop: `for number in range(0, 71, 10):`

Comment: can you kindly explain?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python for increment inner loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13410392/python-for-increment-inner-loop)

Answer (score 0):

Even though I don't understand quite why you want to do this using a while loop, you can change your code to:

```
limitstart = 0
limitend = 0
limit = 55
while limitend < limit:
    limitstart = limitend
    if limitstart + 10 > limit:
        limitend = limitstart + (limit-limitend)
    else:
        limitend = limitstart + 10
    limitstart += 1
    print (limitstart)
    print (limitend)
    print ("new batch")
```

Output:

```
1
10
new batch
11
20
new batch
21
30
new batch
31
40
new batch
41
50
new batch
51
55
new batch
```

Comment: Thank you very much. But could i have done it any other way? Probably a for loop? I am open to more ideas and answers please

Answer (score 0):

Also as a for loop:

```
limit=55
for i in range(1,limit,10):
    print(i)
    print(i+9 if i+9 <= limit else i+(limit-i))
    print("new batch")
```

output:

```
1
10
new batch
11
20
new batch
21
30
new batch
31
40
new batch
41
50
new batch
51
55
new batch
```